# Find (XML) Node on DOM with PHP

Tags: php, xml, dom, wsdl

I'm having trouble finding some node on WSDL (XML) document with DOMDocument PHP. When I use getElementsByTagName it always return NULL. what I'm about to find is xsd:complexType but when I try different node, let say types, it's return a object.

This is my WSDL (XML) Document

```
<definitions xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:tns="urn:routeDx2" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" targetNamespace="urn:routeDx2">
<types>
<xsd:schema targetNamespace="urn:routeDx2"
>
 <xsd:import namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" />
 <xsd:import namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" />
 <xsd:complexType name="inputCashin">
  <xsd:all>
   <xsd:element name="userName" type="xsd:string"/>
   <xsd:element name="signature" type="xsd:string"/>
   <xsd:element name="productCode" type="xsd:string"/>
   <xsd:element name="merchantCode" type="xsd:string"/>
   <xsd:element name="terminal" type="xsd:string"/>
   <xsd:element name="merchantNumber" type="xsd:string"/>
   <xsd:element name="transactionType" type="xsd:string"/>
   <xsd:element name="recipientNumber" type="xsd:string"/>
   <xsd:element name="recipientName" type="xsd:string"/>
   <xsd:element name="amount" type="xsd:string"/>
   <xsd:element name="feeAmount" type="xsd:string"/>
   <xsd:element name="traxId" type="xsd:string"/>
   <xsd:element name="timeStamp" type="xsd:string"/>
  </xsd:all>
 </xsd:complexType>
 <xsd:complexType name="inputCashout">
  <xsd:all>
   <xsd:element name="userName" type="xsd:string"/>
   <xsd:element name="signature" type="xsd:string"/>
   <xsd:element name="productCode" type="xsd:string"/>
   <xsd:element name="merchantCode" type="xsd:string"/>
   <xsd:element name="terminal" type="xsd:string"/>
   <xsd:element name="merchantNumber" type="xsd:string"/>
   <xsd:element name="transactionType" type="xsd:string"/>
   <xsd:element name="recipientNumber" type="xsd:string"/>
   <xsd:element name="recipientName" type="xsd:string"/>
   <xsd:element name="amount" type="xsd:string"/>
   <xsd:element name="feeAmount" type="xsd:string"/>
   <xsd:element name="verifyingCode" type="xsd:string"/>
   <xsd:element name="traxId" type="xsd:string"/>
   <xsd:element name="timeStamp" type="xsd:string"/>
  </xsd:all>
 </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:schema>
</types>
<definitions>
```

what I'm about to find is xsd:complexType or if that's possible, how to find by attribute name that has unique value (verifyingCode or else), how do I accomplish this via PHP and DOMDocument?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Besides your incorrect closing tag for `<definitions>` (last line), I don't see a problem.

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadXML($xml);
$complexTypes = $doc->getElementsByTagName('complexType');
printf('<p>Found %d complexType elements</p>', $complexTypes->length);
foreach ($complexTypes as $complexType) {
    echo $complexType->getAttribute('name'), '<br>';
}
```

Demo - http://codepad.viper-7.com/95XDsS

You're probably including the `xsd` namespace in your tag name query. If you read the [docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php), you will see the argument to `getElementsByTagName()` specifies

> The local name (without namespace) of the tag to match on

Comment: I'm including xsd namespace in my query, this is works. Thanks :)